# Is It Possible to Style Input Rather Than Use Textarea?

Tags: html, css

I've got some text that will eventually make its way into a single-line of a PDF.  Because the PDF area won't have new lines to display this, I would like to use an input rather than a textarea.  Inputs do not allow new lines natively and textareas require you to catch keydown events and do regex when the value changes.

Is there a way of styling an input to have it display similar to a textarea?  [I've tried to accomplish it with CSS](http://jsbin.com/ihotid/1/edit) but the results don't look very promising.

Comment: In short, no. That's why `textarea` exists. You don't _have_ to trap keystrokes in the textarea as it's being edited. You could simply strip the newlines after the form is submitted.

Comment: Have you taken a look into CKEditor?  It has an "in-line" feature where it seems you can write in an editable div (HTML5)

Comment: @ntgCleaner What?  CKEditor is a WYSIWYG HTML editor.  I want a paper-weight, not an anvil.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica You're turning your paperweight into an anvil by using an input text box as a text area.  all the work is done for you.  Yes, it's a large plugin - but it works.  IMO you either need to make an hidden input box that edits the "contents" of a div (to make it look like you're editing a div), use CKEditor or stick with an input

Comment: @MikeW That's what I figured.  I've got no problem handling those events or anything, I just figured there might be a way of styling the input somehow.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Hahahaha, no.  It's a ~300kB file without configs or styles.  How could you ever add 300kB adding a few events to a textarea?

Comment: @MikeW If you want to put your answer up I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. That's why textarea exists. You don't have to trap keystrokes in the textarea as it's being edited. You could simply strip the newlines after the form is submitted.

Comment: The unfortunate truth about the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DIV with `contentEditable` set to `true`. Give this a try:

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width:200px; height:200px; border:solid 1px blue; overflow:auto"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4EgZ9/1/

Comment: That would require more scripting than a `<textarea>` to handle though, it seems the OP wants to avoid scripting.

Comment: I've got no problem with using JavaScript or setting up events, I was hoping for a simple CSS solution.  Judging by the responses, I'll need to handle this with JS.

Comment: DIV *is* pretty much HTML/CSS solution. Not much additional scripting should be involved

Comment: The only thing it requires is the HTML5 support. :/

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Other than the newlines.

Comment: @MVP I don't think so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: @YuriyGalanter You are right as far as what the attribute concerns. But check the event support. It's a mess.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica yes `.innerHTML` will give you HTML's `<p>` and `<br>` instead of newlines, dunno if it's better or not. `.textContent` will give you just text, but newlines just removed (and so is any separation between texts).

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Ahh, I didn't know about those methods.  I'm still going to have to use a textarea in this situation.  I do like the idea of using `contenteditable` though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use textarea, the only way is to use a div containing the wrapped text and whenever the user clicks on it (focus) an input is shown on top that allows editing. Still, this would be pretty ugly, since the user had to edit his text in a single line.

http://jsfiddle.net/3a6LN/

requires CSS3

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: Yeah you can do it, but it would end up looking pretty ugly, especially in the situation that I'm trying to use.  I'll quit hoping for a CSS solution and just get to coding.  :P